# Unable to POST to URL from within a client's network

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

```
PostMethod post = new PostMethod(strURL);
try {
  post.setRequestEntity(new InputStreamRequestEntity(new FileInputStream(input), input.length()));
  post.setRequestHeader("Content-type","text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");

  HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
  HostConfiguration config = httpclient.getHostConfiguration();
  config.setProxy("zz.zz.zz.zz", 1111);

  String username = "username";
  String password = "password";
  Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);
  AuthScope authScope = new AuthScope("zz.zz.zz.zz", 1111);
  httpclient.getState().setProxyCredentials(authScope, credentials);

  int result = httpclient.executeMethod(post);
```

The above code works fine when I am outside client network. Could someone please check if anything wrong in the code

```
Dec 29, 2015 2:34:26 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection timed out: connect
Dec 29, 2015 2:34:26 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: Retrying request
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: if code doesn't run *inside* client network, and word fine *ouside* - check firewall and proxy settings of client network.

Comment: Yes, I tried setting proxy, but still no luck

Comment: If the code works on a different network, then it seems very unlikely to be a problem with the code. Have you ruled out all other options? For example, what happens if you try the same request from `curl`, or within a browser? Have you tried speaking to your client's IT department, to determine whether something is being blocked?

Comment: Thanks  @DaveyDaveDave. It works fine from SOAP UI. So I believe it is not a problem network side